# Use of undeclared identifier 'Token'

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I was writing an interpreter in C, but the complexity was too high. I started put the code into cpp classes and I get an error:

```
#ifdef _TOKEN_H
#define _TOKEN_H
enum TOKEN_TYPE {INTEGER, IDENTIFIER, KEYWORD, OPERATOR, UNKNOWN};

class Token
{
  public:
    Token(string v = "", TOKEN_TYPE t = UNKNOWN);

  private:
    string value;
    TOKEN_TYPE type;
};

#endif
```

And the Token.cpp

```
#include "Token.h"
using namespace std;

Token::Token(string v, TOKEN_TYPE t)
{
   value = v;
   type = t;
}
```

Use of undeclared identifier 'Token'

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Check the include guard...

Comment: I think everybody has to make this mistake at least once. It's a right of passage.

Comment: Also, [read this old answer about use of leading underscores in symbols](http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/440558). Short version: Leading underscore followed by a capital letter is reserved in all scopes.

Comment: Oh, and here's the next one that will trip you up: typing `=` when you mean `==`.

Answer (score 3):

Your header guard is incorrect. It should read:

```
#ifndef _TOKEN_H
// ^
```

Also, tokens beginning with an underscore and capital letter are reserved for any use by the implementation. So it should be:

```
#ifndef TOKEN_H
```

Or even `#ifndef TOKEN_H_GUARD`

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. `#ifdef _TOKEN_H` needs to be `#ifndef _TOKEN_H`. (Also avoid leading underscores followed by capital letters as, technically, the behaviour of the program will be undefined).
2. Use `std::string` in place of `string` in your header, as you're including the header before `using namespace std;`

Writing `using namespace std;` in a header can case problems with namespace pollution so what you're currently doing is preferable.